# CMD or BAT to copy/replace files from a relative path to a .lnk target location

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

Example :

I will have the following :

- Folder that contains :

  1. The CMD or BAT file
  2. the file/files needed to be copied ( Ex: file1.exe and file2.exe )
- A .lnk located at the desktop ( Ex: C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Example.lnk) which is a shortcut for ( EX: D:\folder\Example.pdf )

I need the CMD/BAT file to copy file1.exe and file2.exe from its current relative location and paste or paste/replace them to the .lnk target location after reading it which is D:\folder\

Edit

---

I have tried the following to replace gravity.pdf with another version of gravity.pdf located at the same folder of the bat command :

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem get the .lnk target directory
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%i in (`type "C:\Users\Abdo\Desktop\Gravity.lnk ^| find "\" ^| findstr/b "[a-z][:][\\]"`) do (
  set _targetdir=%%~dpi
  )
rem copy the files
copy /y Gravity.pdf %_target%
endlocal
```

but an error comes "the syntax of the command is incorrect."

I am tring to understand the code , canot get how %_target% will refere to the target full path of the gravity.lnk which at my case now is D:\Books\

Edit 2

---

I have removed some inserted lines from the code and now an empty cmd black window opens but nothing changes :

code :

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem get the .lnk target directory
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%i in (`type "C:\Users\Abdo\Desktop\Gravity.lnk ^| find "\" ^| findstr/b "[a-z][:][\\]"`) do (set _targetdir=%%~dpi)
rem copy the files
copy /y Gravity.pdf %_target%
endlocal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I copy/replace files from a relative path to a .lnk target location?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem get the .lnk target directory
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%i in (`type "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Example.lnk" ^| find "\" ^| findstr/b "[a-z][:][\\]"`) do (
  set _targetdir=%%~dpi
  )
rem copy the files
copy /y file1.exe %_targetdir%
copy /y file2.exe %_targetdir%
endlocal
```

---

#### My code gives an error "the syntax of the command is incorrect".

- You are missing the `"` after `lnk` in the `for` command.
- `%_target%` should be `%_targetdir%` (that was a mistake in my batch file - now fixed).

Here is the corrected version of your batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem get the .lnk target directory
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%i in (`type "C:\Users\Abdo\Desktop\Gravity.lnk" ^| find "\" ^| findstr/b "[a-z][:][\\]"`) do (
  set _targetdir=%%~dpi
  )
rem copy the files
copy /y Gravity.pdf %_targetdir%
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: Edited my post @davidpostill

Comment: @thelordabdo You are missing the `"` after `lnk` in the `for` command. Check my answer and see how it is different from your code.

Comment: That missing `"` is a syntax error. If you have a syntax error then `%_targetdir%` will be undefined. I also made a mistake in my answer (now fixed). Replace `%_target%` with `%_targetdir%` (twice)